# Python replace '' with "" to parse json

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Im currently trying to get a response from a mongodb server then parse the json but when i try to parse the string it returns this error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2

Here is an example string

```
{'Name': 'samplename', 'email': 'email@email'}
```

Can i get a response from the mongodb database as prober json or should i replace the '' with ""

```
import pymongo
import json

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = myclient["shop"]
mycol = mydb["clients"]

for x in mycol.find({},{ "_id": 0, "Name": 1, "email": 1 }):
  y = str(x)
  y = json.loads(y)
  #gets all the names
  print(y["Name"])
```

Comment: `from bson.json_util import loads`, see https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html

Comment: It would appear that `x` is *already* an ordinary `dict`; there's no need to turn it into a `str`, then try to parse it as JSON. `for x in ...: print(x['Name'])`.

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Unless `x` is *already* a JSON string (in which case `y = str(x)` is unnecessary; pass `x` directly to `json.loads`), `str` is not going to *produce* JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is already a `dict`; there's no need to (try to) turn it into JSON only to parse it as a `dict` again.

```
for x in mycol.find({},{ "_id": 0, "Name": 1, "email": 1 }):
    print(x["Name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function dumps

```
import json
# a Python object (dict):
x = {
'name': 'john',
'age': 30,
'city': 'New York'
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# the result is a JSON string :
print(y)
```

Comment: This solves the problem of turning a `dict` into JSON, but it's not a problem the OP needs to solve in the first place.